# What is the best practice for checking if the value exists before using it in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom hook that fetches data and then I want to display that data.

But it isn't available at render so I've been doing this

```
<li>{data && data.name}</li>
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
{data.name && 
  <li>{data.name}</li>
}
```

This way the tag is only rendered if the exact value exists otherwise no element will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

the best way and much more optimized way is

```
<li>{data?.name}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
{data && <li>data.name</li>}
```